# What format should I convert my iTunes Videos to?

Tags: video, itunes, conversion, encoding, format

Recently got Daniusoft Media Converter, and was about to strip the DRM off my iTunes library, then I found I had a huge decision to make.

Converting my music seems obvious, to MP3, however the video formats, I'm at a loss on.

It has "optimized" formats for all types of video players such as iPhone, Zune, Droid (which I own), and just a huge list!

I bought several seasons of House and a few movies, though I don't know which format would be optimal to not lose quality.

While I love my Droid, I have no intention on watching full episodes or movies on it, and I have a feeling that would reduce quality.

One of the options sections is HD Video, and it has HD MPEG-4 Video (*.mp4).

That one seems like it would be the best format to convert to without losing quality, but again, I'm unsure.

**Has anyone used this software, or have general expertise in video formats to give a recommendation on what file format I should convert my videos to?**

Format requirements:

No loss in quality
Portability would be ideal (as in, will play on my Windows and potentially MAC, and streamable to a bigscreen).

Comment: Explanation for down vote please?

Comment: It wasn't me.. but my guess is that it was because you are removing DRM and therefore breaking a legal agreement. Personally I don't think you should be allowed to downvote without an explanation unless there is one already-explained downvote in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos purchased from the iTunes Store are in a protected HD MPEG-4 format, with the video encoded at H.264 and the audio as AAC. Therefore, stripping the DRM and converting to that generic HD MPEG-4 video (with mp4 file extension) would probably be best for least loss of quality (if at all) and portability. You can always use Daniusoft again to convert to a specific format like PS3, Zune, etc.